# Copy a meta_value of a meta_key to another meta_key in the same table

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

The two WordPress installs, Master and Slave, that share the same database.

- The database prefix for the first install Master is "wp_master_"
- The database prefix for the second install Slave is "wp_slave_"

The two installs share the same user base "wp_master_users" and "wp_master_usermeta".

In "wp_master_usermeta" table, the user capabilities are stored in

- "wp_master_capabilities" meta_key for the Master, and
- "wp_slave_capabilities" meta_key for the Slave

I want "wp_slave_capabilities" to have the same meta_value as that of "wp_master_capabilities".

I think this can be executed by a SQL query so that the meta_key of "wp_master_capabilities" is copied to the meta_key of "wp_slave_capabilities".

But I don't know much about writing SQL queries that actually work.

Would anyone be able to help me structure a SQL query to accomplish the task?

Thanks!

Comment: Ever thought about using Multisite instead?

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for the idea. I am testing multisite setup as well. I already have two separate WordPress installs. So if I can get this working, then I don't have to go for multisite. But if I can not, I have no choice but to try multisite.

Comment: How did you get the Slave install to use the Master user base? It seems as if you are trying to do something in a rather complex way that WP can do out of the box.

Comment: Hi Michael, what do you mean by "WP can do out of the box"? Do you mean multisite setup? I didn't know earlier about a multisite setup. So I went for two separate WordPress installations that share the same database. You can read this post for more details: https://kinsta.com/blog/share-logins-wordpress/. Switching to multisite looks complex at this stage as my websites have grown since. One is a woocommerce site with 6000+ orders and 7000+ users, and the other is a WordPress blog with 200+ posts.